# App crashing when clicking on the button to show Alert Dialog

Tags: android, api, android-linearlayout

I created a alert dialog behind the onclick of a button but when i click that button it crashes the app throw the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity
```

> 07-13 11:51:12.445 21054-21054/com.vshine.neuron.riseshine
>   E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!

in logcat that I couldn't able to understand as I'm new to coding, .Java and Logcat screenshots are attached.
This is Logcat :

[image]

This is .java class :

[image]

Comment: can you provide a full logcat?

Comment: share **style.xml**

Comment: can you  show me Manifest file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity you can try a lot of suggestions from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think you need to provide context of the Activity.
Try this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(YourClassName.this)
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage("Message?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Function on no
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       //Function on yes
                    }
                })
                .show();
```

Comment: I only changed new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationcontext()) to (quiz.this) and it worked.Can you please tell me the difference as both approaches are fine to go with.

Answer (score 0):

just try to inherit `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` to your `quiz.java` activity

like at top of code

```
public class Quiz extends Activity{
```

for more check [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815015/6834114)

Comment: It didn't work.Still app is crashing when I click the button